# How do I use Scrapy with no specific start URL?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm attempting to use Scrapy to collect data from `http://www.guidestar.org` search results, but the way the website is set up, when I make a specific search for an organization on the website, the URL for the results is just

```
http://www.guidestar.org/SearchResults.aspx
```

which I can't plug in as the start URL since it doesn't link to any actual search results. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests